# Can't find which view triggered the tap gesture recognizer in my custom view

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I know a lot of questions are answered for the issues like this but in my case, the common answers do not work.

I have a custom view which is a small view that appears above the active textfield to show the clipboard data so if the user wants that data in that textField, taps on my custom view so the clipboard text automatically pastes into that textField.

[image]

everything works fine when there is a single textField on the page. but if I add another textField, this custom view can't detect the correct textField to paste the text into it.

here is my code inside my customView to detect current textField

```
private func addTapGesture() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    tap.delegate = self
    window?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view!.frame.contains(subviews.first!.frame) {
            tapComple?(true)
        } else {
            tapComple?(false)
        }
        return true
    }
```

I know that already other answers on the stackoverflow are saing to use this:

```
if touch.view == self
```

But it is not working in my case...

[The demo project to see everything.](https://www.filemail.com/d/zxtpnxgywevtbrl)

Comment: So when input focus changes, you change the small custom view's frame to overlap with the input?  If so, instead, add the gr to the custom view, and give the custom view a property that you set to the input it was just framed over.  Then the view you're looking for will be `touch.view.theInputIAmFramedOver`.

Comment: You need to detect which view this is and therefore which text field this is.

Comment: @danh When the input focus changes, I remove my view & create a new one! I can't undrestand what you are saying... sorry. did you check my demo project?

Comment: @matt Yes of course... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect if the rectangle contains the point which you touched. You can achieve that with the code below.

Change your `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecieve:)` method to the following:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if subviews.first?.frame.contains(touch.location(in: subviews.first)) == true {
        print(true)
        tapComple?(true)
    } else {
        print(false)
        tapComple?(false)
    }
    return true
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank god you arrived! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any calculations or listening gesture recognizer delegate.

Instead of that you can add tap gesture recognizer on your own view, on on the `window`. So all taps it receive - will be correct ones.

Also right now you're adding your view as subview to text field. This is really a bad practice and will stop this view from receiving taps.

Instead of that I suggest you adding it to to `UIViewController` `view`. To do so you need to pass two views into your `LContextView`: `superview` and `anchorView` on which you'll bind your constraints

```
private func configView(superView: UIView, anchorView: UIView, size: CGSize) {
    removePreviusContexes(superView: superView)
    superView.addSubview(self)
    backgroundColor = .white
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
    centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchorView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchorView.centerYAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
    ...
```

```
private func addTapGesture() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
    addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```